# Quickly parse tab-separated strings and ints in c++

Tags: c++, parsing, optimization, io, bigdata

I have a file which is a couple gigabytes large, and has millions of lines. Each line has data separated like so:

```
string TAB int TAB int TAB int NEWLINE
```

My previous attempts to read this line by line have bottle necked as a result of the CPU instead of my SSD's write speed.

How can I quickly parse a massive file line by line?

*Note: The files can't be parsed into a vector all at once because they are too large.*

In my original code I was parsing the data into vector of structs like this

```
struct datastruct {
    std::string name;
    int year;
    int occurences;
    int volcount;
};
std::vector<datastruct> data;
```

Comment: What do you want to parse it to?

Comment: @flatmouse In my testing I was using a vector of structs

Comment: @flatmouse see my edit

Comment: What is the end result you are trying to obtain? Validation of the file? Output to something else?

Comment: @flatmouse I am doing some statistical analysis of the data, which I've worked out. The problem I'm having is with quickly parsing the data.

Comment: You keep saying to want to do it fast. What do you want to make faster? You can parse without writing it all to memory. Do you want it written to another file in the end?

Comment: @flatmouse In the end, the resultant data will probably only be a few MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `datastruct`, you could do

```
std::ifstream file;
datastruct data;
while (file >> data.name >> data.year >> data.occurences >> data.volcount)
{
    // do what you want with data, its contents will be replaced during next iteration
}
```

Is that that slow?

Comment: @FelisPhasma I thought the file was too big for a `vector`?

Comment: @flatmouse correct. A line-by-line approach is better because it doesn't copy the whole file into ram.

Comment: @FelisPhasma This does not even operate on lines. Even if your file would be on single line, it would still read it element after element (obviously, `istream` uses some kind of internal buffer, so something will be in ram)

Comment: This is a good answer for the question in the current form. It makes no assumptions about what happens with the data after parsing.

Comment: This certainly appears to be faster, but the bottleneck is still the CPU instead of the hard drive... Any other thoughts?

Comment: And @flatmouse, you are correct, this is very helpful

Comment: @flatmouse Just good as question though, it does not outline what it does with the data

Comment: I made a couple smaller optimizations to my internal code, and with this IO method it is many times faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It might be worth implementing a custom `istream& operator>>(istream&, datastruct&)` to make the code easier to read and manage.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is optional improvement to readability and maintainability but does not have to do anything with performance or functionality.

Comment: @Zereges it can, actually, if the format of the lines ever changes, new fields are added, etc. Instead of updating the loop, you update the `operator>>` instead. You can then optimize the `operator>>` as needed.